# Using event log in windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, event-log

Recently I finished developing a windows service. It is working on my PC, easy start and logging but unfortunately it doesn't setup on other computers very easy due to the fact that I use event log. As I try googling I found that I should setup some permissions over registry and users.
Why this is so complicated and how can i solve it...

```
public MainService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ServiceName = "Network Support Service";
            //eventlog
            this.EventLog.Log = "Application";
            if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("NetworkSupportSource"))
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("NetworkSupportSource", "NetworkSupportLOG");
            eventLog1.Source = "NetworkSupportSource";
            eventLog1.Log = "NetworkSupportLOG";
            //مقداردهی رشته اتصال
            ConnectionString = NetworkSupportWS.Properties.Settings.Default.paneldbConnectionString;

        }
```

Any help on how to create a setup that can handle it.
Any sample.

I use `LocalService` as `ServiceProcessInstaller` account!

Comment: hello please delete your comments in other languages refigh?!!مقدار دهی رشته اتصال

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create the source as administrator, then every program can log to it. This is shown in the manual:

> [`EventLog.CreateEventSource()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2awhba7a(v=vs.100).aspx):
>
> **Note**
>
> To create an event source in Windows Vista and later or Windows Server 2003, you must have administrative privileges.

Comment: ANY SAmples, some code plz or just drop me a link. thanks for reply

Comment: @MAYSAMGAMINI I don't know how you install this service. You should be able to let its installer require administrative rights and then you can create the event source.

Comment: Dear CodeCaster as You can See in My code i am already use System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource but i think i need to install my service in a different account, now i use LocalService as ServiceProcessInstaller account

Comment: @MAYSAMGAMINI guessing (_"I think I need..."_) will not help, reading will. As I said: the `CreateEventSource()` needs to be run as administrator once, then every program can write to that source.